# Ready event handler times out

Tags: c#, bots, discord

I'm currently working on a Discord bot written in C#. It is supposed to celebrate the birthday of the users in a server, once they have provided their day and month of birth by sending a message (user-birthday pairs are stored inside a local .txt file). A birthday is celebrated by sending an embed in the main channel of the guild (with which it shares the ID parameter) if the date of execution happens to be someone's birthday.

The content of the Ready event handler of the DiscordSocketClient element within the Program class and a partial call stack are shown below:

```
    public DiscordSocketClient Client;
    //...
    private async Task Client_Ready()
    {
        await Commands.CelebrateUsers(Client);
    }
```

also

```
    public static async Task CelebrateUsers(DiscordSocketClient client)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        List<ulong> users = new List<ulong>();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"docs\birthdays.txt"))
        {
            string date;
            ulong user;
            while ((date = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                user = Convert.ToUInt64(reader.ReadLine());
                int[] dm = date.Split(' ').Select(x=>Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();
                if(now.Day == dm[0] && now.Month == dm[1])
                {
                    foreach(SocketGuild g in client.Guilds)
                    {
                        if(g.Users.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id == user) != null)
                             await CelebrateUser(user, g);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static async Task CelebrateUser(ulong id, SocketGuild guild)
    {
        var embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        {
            Title = "Auguri ",
            Color = Discord.Color.Green,
            ThumbnailUrl = "https://c7.uihere.com/files/240/249/186/hot-air-balloon-birthday-balloon.jpg",
            ImageUrl = guild.GetUser(id).GetAvatarUrl(size:900),
            Footer =
            {
                IconUrl = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/406195350903193600/9629b569007720204f7fe775a9be0aeb.png",
                Text = "Generato da DrKikkoCeccato++."
            },
            Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now
        };
        await guild.DefaultChannel.SendMessageAsync("",embed:embed.Build());
    }
```

However, I have an issue with the last function. The last piece of code (the "SendMessageAsync" part) is not even called.
Upon the initialization of the embed, the Log event of the DiscordSocketClient is fired with the following records:

**"A Ready handler is blocking the gateway task."**

**"A Ready handler has thrown an unhandled exception."**

The state changes to "Ready" immediately afterwards. Needless to say, my embed is not being sent.
I don't get what the problem might be, since every action is marked as "asynchronous" (in order to avoid problems with the 3-second timeout of the "Ready" event). Could anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would guess that somewhere in your EmbedBuilder constructor or in the property setting of the same class an exception is being thrown. Could you maybe try to wrap  await Commands.CelebrateUsers(Client);  with a try catch to see if an exception is being thrown?

Comment: Thanks, the Footer object in the EmbedBuilder was not properly initialized.